# Convert Random String to Enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have defined this enum where a client could pass in some random types and I want to convert them to a consistent useable form:

```
package com.amazon.dvpatemplateselectionservice.types;

public enum Cases {
    LOWERCASE("lowercase"), UPPERCASE("UPPERCASE"), CAMEL("camelCased");

    private final String someCase;

    Cases(final String inputCase) {
        this.someCase = inputCase;
    }
}
```

When I call this in my code, I want the input from the client to convert to the enum:

```
Cases whatever = Cases.valueOf(Cases.class, requestParams.getValue());

Class someClass = new Class(whatever);
```

And the error I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: camelCased is not a constant in Cases
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to look it up manually. And `case` as a field name will not compile

Comment: `case` is not a valid identifier

Comment: Yeah that's just a random example I gave. I'll change in the question though.

Comment: What @ernest_k said.  Also you need to add logic to handle the case where the user passes in a string that doesn't map to an enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method in your `enum` (I renamed `case` to `_case` as `case` is a forbidden java keyword) :

```
public static Cases fromLabel(String label)
{
    return Stream.of(Cases.values())
    .filter(c -> c._case.equals(label))
    .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

and then :

```
Cases whatever = Cases.fromLabel("camelCased");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `name` parameter to `Enum#valueOf` expects the enum name exactly as declared, and that won't work with your input.

You will need to use a custom lookup method such as `find` below:

```
enum Cases {
    LOWERCASE("lowercase"), UPPERCASE("UPPERCASE"), CAMEL("camelCased");

    private final String caze;

    Cases(final String inputCase) {
        this.caze = inputCase;
    }

    public static Cases find(String c) {
        //you can also just loop
        return Stream.of(values()).filter(v -> v.caze.equals(c))
                 .findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Cases whatever = Cases.find(requestParams.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Cases.valueOf(String)` is looking for the constant-name of the enum items. For your example, that's `LOWERCASE`, `UPPERCASE` and `CAMEL`.

If you want to look up an enum item from a field, write a method to do it.

```
public static Cases fromString(String string) {
    return Arrays.stream(Cases.values())
                 .filter(x -> x.someCase.equals(string))
                 .findAny()
                 .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No such case: "+string));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)` tries to create an enum of type `enumType` with the given `name` ([see Enum.valueOf javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-)).

Thus, you have to construct a custom lookup method that uses at the field you called `case` to construct an enum of type Cases.